# WiFi Broadcast Receiver is never called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I trying to register a wifi receiver, and i did as shown in the code posted below, the problem is when i intentionally disable the wifi in the device and run the code, the `Toast` in the `else` statement in the `BroadCast Receiver` is never called.

**code**:

```
OnClickListener mainFramListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)){
                MQTT_Connection_Module();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No WiFi-Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
};
```

**Permissions**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I believe that onReceive() is only called when discoverPeers() is successful AND there are peers nearby.  Thus, when you turn your wifi off you won't be able to detect any peers and onReceive will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
//put this in your activity, service, or whatever

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isWifiConnected = false;
        boolean isMobileConnected = false;

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if(networkInfo != null)
        isWifiConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();

        networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(networkInfo != null)
        isMobileConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();  

        Log.d("network status", "wifi == " + isWifiConnected + " and mobile == " + isMobileConnected);

        }
    };

//registering the receiver from activity, service

registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, 
           new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

//or 

context.registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, 
           new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)); //where context it's a Context class object


//manifest 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



// see http://androidsnippets.com/network-connectivity-changes
```

Comment: which intent filter should i use